# Grails - how to load a template using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

Here's what i've done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#botao").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();        
        var loading = new Image();
        loading.src = "images/spinner.gif"        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "index.gsp",
            data: <missing>,  
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#divForm").html(loading);
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#divForm").html(data);
            },            
        });
    });
});
```

how can I pass my template using a button to load it in a div called #divForm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your trying to load index.gsp page in #divForm Id, So i wrote this simple ajax code.

#.In the following code contains controllerName in this place you need to put your own controller Name.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){    
           $("#botao").click(function (ev) {   
              $.ajax({
                    url: "${createLink(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'form')}",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divForm").html(data);
                    }
                 });
              });
           });
```

Comment: i'm not trying to load index.gsp in #divForm, index.gsp is the page where the div is located, what i want to load in there is a template called _form.gsp

Comment: Exactly, if you want to load  _form.gsp in your index page. you need to create action name in your controller [action name and your template name might be same].

Comment: and what should this controller do? can you please show an example?