# how to render a response to a specific place on a gsp grails

Tags: grails, web, rendering, gsp

I am new to grails and groovy.
I am trying to find out how to render a response from an action in a grails controller IN THE SAME gsp - but in a DIFFERENT SECTION OF THE gsp  - as the gsp that takes the request (in this case a web form gsp page)?

any links or turorials or just straight to the point "do this" kind of replies are welcomed.

I tried to google search for it, but I was not sure what to use as a search term and I could not find a concise answer.

```
========= UPDATE TO QUESTION (INCLUDING SOME CODE) =========
```

Here is the code I am working with. It is a Grails application in which I am using a bootstrap template (available for free on the internet of course).

Now the actual code itself for functionality works. What I am having an issue with is this:

I have a gsp page that uses a css template and another gsp temlate for layout. I can start the page as inside the gsp+css tempate using this code (snippet) in my gsp page:

```
<g:layoutBody/>
```

This allows me to call my calling controller code in this gsp file for the request:

```
<body>
<g:form name="form" controller="apiStart" id="form">
    <div><g:select name="protocolType" value="restCall" from="${["-select-", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]}"/> &nbsp <label>URL: </label><g:textField name="url" value="${url}" />
    &nbsp <label>username: </label><g:textField name="userName" value="${userName}" />  &nbsp <label>password: </label><g:textField name="passWord" value="${passWord}" /></div>

    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>URL: </label><g:textField name="url" value="${url}" /></div>--}%
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>username: </label><g:textField name="userName" value="${userName}" /></div>
    <div class="text-field"><label>password: </label><g:textField name="passWord" value="${passWord}" /></div>--}%
    <br>
    <div><label>Use Advanced Parameters?</label><g:checkBox name="useAdvParms" value="${false}" /></div>
    <div class="text-field"><label>Header1: </label><g:textField name="header1" value="${header1}" /> &nbsp <label>Value1: </label><g:textField name="value1" value="${header2}" /></div>
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>Value1: </label><g:textField name="value1" value="${header2}" /></div>--}%
    <div class="text-field"><label>Header2: </label><g:textField name="header2" value="${header3}" /> &nbsp <label>Value2: </label><g:textField name="value2" value="${header4}" /></div>
    %{--<div class="text-field"><label>Value2: </label><g:textField name="value2" value="${header4}" /></div>--}%
    <br>
    <div class="submit"><g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="save"/></div>
</g:form>
</body>
```

And then this gsp code for the response:

```
<body>
<h3>API Test Results</h3>
API Tested: ${apiStart.url}, Response: ${apiStart.response3}
<br>
%{--<g:textArea name="myField" value="myValue" rows="20" cols="100"/>--}%
<div class="textarea"><label>Output</label><br><g:textArea name="myField" value="${apiStart.result3}"  />
</div>
%{--Responce Code: ${apiStart.response3}<br>--}%
%{--Response: <br> ${apiStart.result3} <br>--}%

</body>
```

My issue: it works fine as separate pages. I want to render the results of the request on the same page as the calling request.

in the screen shot attached: I want to put the results in the text box where it says "Output Displayed here...."
[image: screenshot of gsp page]

I assumed templates in grails is the way to go about it. but I get a Java Null pointer exception when I try to insert the template into that part of the code.

Can someone advise and show me the best way to do this?

```
==================== END of Updated question ===================
```

thanks.

ironmantis7x

Comment: Could you provide an example of what are you trying to archive? Are you meaning some ajax stuff?

Comment: I wasn't meaning Ajax stuff. Is there a way to do it in pure graiks/groovy/css/html??? I haven't tried anything yet as I couldn't find any examples to base it off of as I wasn't sure if my question is clear.

Comment: @rvargas  
I wasn't meaning Ajax stuff. Is there a way to do it in pure graiks/groovy/css/html??? I haven't tried anything yet as I couldn't find any examples to base it off of as I wasn't sure if my question is clear.

Comment: So, you have an action and a gsp, and you want to use what you are sending to the view in different sections of the same gsp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448137/grails-how-to-load-a-template-using-ajax/38454554#38454554

Comment: @rvargas yes. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kamalkannan I am hoping not to have to do it in Ajax. Is that the only solution to use Ajax? I am sure Grails has a Solution based on Groovy/Grails/CSS/HTML ... ????

Comment: well, you can use template and add it twice (in both needed places) to that same gsp page. template can be a full page or just a div/table or anything really. If that satisfies your question, I can post it as an answer w/ info and example.

Comment: @ironmantis7x you can render instance and gsp page by following this link. http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Controllers/render.html

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks please post and example of how to do that so I can try it.

Comment: @Kamalkannan I will look at that link. In my gsp layouts I have a template that has a div section where I want the response to go. Is that the div section I specify in the render??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Grails [templates](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates).
Basically Template is a (reusable) part of a View. 
**Info**: 
So you create template file *bookTemplate.gsp*, put all the gsp/html code in there as usual (but just the part, if it will be used in the body, then don't add `html`, `body`, `head` tags etc. 
**Example**:

```
<div class="book" id="${book?.id}">
   <div>Title: ${book?.title}</div>
   <div>Author: ${book?.author?.name}</div>
</div>
```

Then you render that template into the gsp page in places where you want them to be (with a simple grails `render` tag. And it will simply get compiled (as the code from template would be pasted into gsp view). 
**Render**:

```
<g:render template="bookTemplate" model="[book: myBook]" />
```

Comment: I think this will work ... I am trying it now (work has me busy a few days)

Comment: this keeps throwing an error... I forgot to mention I am using a bootstrap theme with my grails application. how do I use a template with a bootstream theme...???

Comment: What's the error? I've never had issues with bootstrap and grails templates.

Comment: when I add the line: 
<g:render template="myTemplate" model="[apiStart: apiStart]" />
I get a java null point exception. 
In my gsp page (which is from a bootstrap theme) I have:
<g:layoutBody/> which shows where to add my formatted gsp code

Comment: It's hard to figure it out without the code you applied to gsp page and the full error. If you could close this one (or maybe leave it open if U think U can get a better answer) and start another question regarding that error, it'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your grails version, but on 2.4.5, and maybe on your version, you can use :
http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html

And have a look to the attribute update :

> update (optional) - Either a Map containing the elements to update for
>   'success' or 'failure' states, or a string with the element id to
>   update, in which case failure events would be ignored

And you also can trigger javascript on some events, ...

In your action called in the submitToRemote button, you can render a template (but do not put your layout in this template if you render a template, otherwise you will have all you website structure rendered...) and it will be displayed in the HTML element with the ID that you have put in "update" property.

The example given in the link is interesting.